# Simple bank-account application using composition

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I'm trying to use composition to design an application that works with different types of bank-accounts. Instead of deriving from a Account Class I want to have separate account classes that are created with appropriate behaviours with a factory. For the example below can I please get some comments on:

1. Overall design decision
2. Testability
3. As i'm adding more behaviours/features does it look sustainable to keep passing objects in constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Balance {
public:
  Balance() {}
  Balance(double amount, std::string currency)
      : d_amount(amount), d_currency(currency) {}
  double amount() const { return d_amount; }
  std::string currency() const { return d_currency; }

private:
  double d_amount;
  std::string d_currency;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Balance &balance) {
  os << "Balance->" << balance.amount() << ":Currency->" << balance.currency();
  return os;
}

class InterestRate {
private:
  double d_interest_rate;

public:
  virtual double interest_rate() const = 0;
};

class CurrentAccountInterestRate : public InterestRate {
public:
  double interest_rate() const override { return 0.5; }
};

class SavingsAccountInterestRate : public InterestRate {
public:
  double interest_rate() const override { return 2.0; }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const InterestRate &interest_rate) {
  os << "Interest-Rate->" << interest_rate.interest_rate() << std::endl;
  return os;
}

class CurrentAccount {
public:
  CurrentAccount(const Balance &balance,
                 std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> interest_rate)
      : d_balance(balance), d_interest_rate(std::move(interest_rate)) {}

  void print_balance() { std::cout << d_balance << ":" << *d_interest_rate; }

private:
  Balance d_balance;
  std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> d_interest_rate;
};

class SavingsAccount {
public:
  SavingsAccount(const Balance &balance,
                 std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> interest_rate)
      : d_balance(balance), d_interest_rate(std::move(interest_rate)) {}

  void print_balance() { std::cout << d_balance << ":" << *d_interest_rate; }

private:
  Balance d_balance;
  std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> d_interest_rate;
};

class AccountFactory {
public:
  static CurrentAccount create_current_account(double amount,
                                               const std::string &currency) {
    std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> currentAccountInterestRate =
        std::make_unique<CurrentAccountInterestRate>();
    CurrentAccount ca{Balance{amount, currency},
                      std::move(currentAccountInterestRate)};
    return ca;
  }

  static SavingsAccount create_savings_account(double amount,
                                               const std::string &currency) {
    std::unique_ptr<InterestRate> savingsAccountInterestRate =
        std::make_unique<SavingsAccountInterestRate>();
    SavingsAccount sa{Balance{amount, currency},
                      std::move(savingsAccountInterestRate)};
    return sa;
  }
};

int main() {
  CurrentAccount ca = AccountFactory::create_current_account(20.5, "USD");
  ca.print_balance();
  SavingsAccount sa = AccountFactory::create_savings_account(40.5, "GBP");
  sa.print_balance();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

```
Balance(double amount, std::string currency)
    : d_amount(amount), d_currency(currency) {}

std::string d_currency;
```

You are taking the `currency` parameter by value, and then copying it to the member, then you don’t need the first copy anymore.  I think you were trying to use the “sink” parameter idiom?

```
 : d_amount{amount}, d_currency{std::move(currency)} {}
```

You forgot the `move`!  Also, you were using old syntax for the initializers: use uniform initialization style now (since C++11).  (Later) I see you did `move` in another class, so that was your intent here I think.

I see you *are* using initializers, which is good.  Likewise, using exactly one of virtual/override/final on a virtual function, and using `unique_ptr`.

---

```
void print_balance() { std::cout << d_balance << ":" << *d_interest_rate; }
```

That’s exactly the same for `CurrentAccount` and `SavingsAccount`.  I thought at first you were overriding a virtual function with no need, but looking closer I see that these classes are not related, and yet they are identical!  I don’t want to do a diff to find out if there is a few chars different *somewhere*, so that is a concern for understandibility.

Likewise, `AccountFactory` is duplicating the same code for both creation functions.  What is the deal here?  If you need “strong types”, just add a template parameter.  Don’t duplicate the entire code for the class manually!

---

Why is `InterestRate` a polymorphic interface?  Is what’s shown here just as example, or is there really nothing more to it than different *values* of a field?  Because in that case, you should just use a value.  This is especially odd since you always use the same Interest Rate class with a corresponding Account class — there is no need to make it polymorphic at all, even if they were really different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments:

1. Yes, my intent was that string should 'move' into it and my assumption was pass-by-value will move if the class has move ctor, but now I realise that it will probably move an rvalue but not an lvalue so should cast it.
2. The deal with the 2 similar classes was that I wanted to avoid inheritance for code-reuse. So even though they are similar, they are different, but I agree that may be in this case a policy-based design would have been better - Was that you suggestion when you said use template?
- Point 3 in next comment

Comment: 3. Yes, InterestRate was an example of a 'behaviour' and composing classes using behaviours . It seems that in a composition based design i'll need inheritance/polymorphism in behaviours rather than entities. Thoughts?

Comment: thoughts:  design use cases that *uses* the kind of composition you are interested in.  Then we can see what you need to accomplish that.  With your current usage/example code, you don’t need anything at all, so it all seems unnecessary.